# how to track walk using gps and work with background service

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am developing one app which is track our walk where over device goes.

I have four buttons.

> start,stop,pause,resume.

**If user click**

```
start button -> start services.
pause button -> stop services
resume button -> start services.
stop button -> stop services
```

**Problem:**

1. Tested app in my device but not getting lat/long when start button click it took 2 to 5 minutes.

   ```
   locationMangaer = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   locationListener = new  MyLocationListener();
   locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 0,locationListener);
   ```
2. Not updating in **100 milliseconds**.
3. If I start application half an hour and i walk then it will get **only 5 to 10 location lat/long**.

**How to improve getting lat/long ever 100 miliseconds.Please give me idea.**

Comment: Try to check in various devices as may be problem of GPS..

Comment: @SilentKiller i am testing two different devices.

Comment: @Harshid Check it outside the building

Comment: @Abhi i am test this app in one the way